# Center a parent div while width retrieves width value of child div

Tags: html, css

As the title tells you, I want to center a parent div where the parent div retrieves the width of all its child divs.

This is the code I used to retrieve the width of the child divs:

```
.parent
{
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    /*How could I center this div? I used to do: margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    however for this I need to assign a fixed width. I want to assign the width of the
    content inside the div.*/
}

.child
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/53me4f8e/

How can I center this div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Centrally align the text of the parent element, in this case, `body`. `.parent` is displayed as an `inline-block`, which means it behaves like an inline element and is therefore centred:

```
body{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note, because `text-align` is inherited, you may want to revert the text alignment back to `left` (or `right`, depending on preference) for `.parent`:

```
.parent{
  text-align: left;
  /* Other styles.. */
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/53me4f8e/3/)

Comment: Ah ofcourse, thanks for sharing this. Sometimes the answer seesms to be easier than I thought it should've been.

Comment: @Barrosy Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
.parent{
display: block;
text-align:center;
}
```

[**updated your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/53me4f8e/4/)